# Windows workflow type load exception

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation

I am building a state machine with windows workflow, and I am trying to new up an object from another assembly in my solution.  When I build the solution, I get a TypeLoadException from the StateActivityValidator (which runs after a successful build  to see that all the required properties are set and such).

The type I am trying to create an instance of is very simple, it has a default public constructor, and both assemblies are signed.  Any ideas what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was caused by having mismatched versions of these assemblies in the GAC.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this other assembly isn't loaded before WF is trying to deserialize.  You can test this by simply new-ing up an instance of this type before your application starts executing (i.e., in the Main method of your Program class, for a winforms app).

If this is a case, you can try a few things.

**First**, force loading of all assemblies you need in memory before deserialization (like the test above).  This method, imho, sucks.

**Second**, [you can add logic to runtime type resolution.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.typeresolve.aspx)  It appears to be possible, but I've never done it.

**Third**, modify your serialized workflow to give it the information you need to load the type.

I'm not sure how you are serializing your workflow, so I can't tell you exactly how to do this.  I can tell you that workflows are serialized to xaml.  The XamlReader can, on deserialization, load assemblies of types included in the xaml.  This is done by using a [special type of XML namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx).

Let's say this is your missing type (in a serialized workflow):

```
<MyType><!--blahblah--></MyType>
```

and MyType is defined, in the assembly MyCode.DLL:

```
namespace MyCodeNamespace
{
  public class MyType { /*yadda*/ }
}
```

then the namespace for this type would be:  `clr-namespace:MyCodeNamespace;assembly=MyCode`
and it would appear in your serialized workflow as:

```
<MyType namespace="clr-namespace:MyCodeNamespace;assembly=MyCode"><!--blahblah--></MyType>
```

The XamlReader recognizes that namespace, determines the assembly is called MyCode.DLL or MyCode.EXE, looks for it, loads it in memory, and looks for MyCodeNamespace.MyType.

The question then becomes, "how do I get my workflow to serialize that namespace???"  The answer is "I dunno".  Perhaps you can use the following assembly attributes:

```
[assembly: XmlnsPrefix("clr-namespace:MyCodeNamespace;assembly=MyCode", "MyCode")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("clr-namespace:MyCodeNamespace;assembly=MyCode", "MyCodeNamespace")]
```

but I'm not sure if the Workflow serializer will respect these.  Hell, I'm not even sure if the Workflow serializer will respect the clr-namespace in the first place. You can try it out, and if not ask another question on SO based on this.

Comment: This is a SharePoint workflow, so I don't have an easy way to try creating the object sooner... I think SharePoint is handling the serialization of my workflow, so I don't know that I can add any logic to that process.

Comment: Bugger.  My only other suggestion is that you use the fusion log to see if its something simple, such as the loader not looking where the assembly is.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your help Will, I can create other objects from that assembly, so it seems like it must have something to do with that specific type...